# knights tour using a stack

Tags: c++, stack, backtracking, heuristics, knights-tour

I'm tasked with solving the Knights tour iteratively using a stack to store the previous moves so I can pop if the knight is stuck. My program seems to be making multiple POPS but doesn't seem to be ever solving the puzzle.
It uses Warnsdorffs rule for the first 32 moves and then uses a stack to solve the remaining spaces.

Is there something wrong with my logic so that it never solves the puzzle?

Is this a legal move function

```
bool safe(int row, int col) {

        if (row >= 0 && row < 8 && col >= 0 && col < 8 && arr[row][col] == -1){

            return true;

            }
            return false;
}// end safe
```

Here is the solve function

```
void solve(){
    int x = 0; // initial start
    int y = 0; // initial start
    arr[0][0] = 0; // loading array with starting position
    int nextMoveX, nextMoveY; // next move
    Location top;
    top.x = 0;
    top.y = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        top.movesArray[i] = safe(top.x+moveX[i], top.y+moveY[i]);

    }

    locate.push(top); // loading stack with initial position
    int bestMove[8]; // array to sort best move
    int counter = 0; // move counter
    int count = 0;
    while(counter < 63){


        top = locate.top(); // check top of stack for current position
        x = top.x;
        y = top.y;


            //loops through the 8 move choices


                // using a stack to solve final steps
                if( counter >= 31){


                    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                            top = locate.top();

                            if(top.movesArray[i]){

                                    if(counter == 42){

                                        cout << i;

                                    }
                               //updates the top of the stack removing the
                                move just made from being made on a POP
                                top.movesArray[i] = false;
                                locate.pop();
                                locate.push(top);


                                counter++;
                                nextMoveX = x + moveX[i];
                                nextMoveY = y + moveY[i];
                                arr[nextMoveX][nextMoveY] = counter;
                                top.x = nextMoveX;
                                top.y = nextMoveY;
                                print();
                                cout << counter;

                                for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                                    top.movesArray[j] = safe(nextMoveX+moveX[j], nextMoveY+moveY[j]);
                                    cout << top.movesArray[j];
                                }
                                locate.push(top);


                                break;
                            }
                            //if no more valid moves from this space pop off
                            if(i == 7){

                                    arr[top.x][top.y]= -1;
                                locate.pop();
                                counter --;
                                cout << "pop";
                                top = locate.top();
                                for(int a = 0; a < 8; a++){
                                    cout << top.movesArray[a];
                                }

                                break;


                            }




                    }
                }

                // heuristics for first 32 moves
                else{
                    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                        bestMove[i] = -1; // resets # of potential moves at next space

                        print();

                            // test next position
                        nextMoveX = x + moveX[i];
                        nextMoveY = y + moveY[i];

                        //if safe count number of moves on next space
                        if(safe(nextMoveX,nextMoveY)){

                            for( int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
                                if(safe(nextMoveX+moveX[j],nextMoveY+moveY[j])){
                                    bestMove[i] += 1;

                                }

                            }

                        }
                        //if on last move check for one with least moves available
                        if(i ==7){

                            int least = 8;
                            int pos = -1;
                            int L;

                            for(L = 0; L < 8; L++){
                                if(bestMove[L] < least && bestMove[L] != -1 && bestMove[L]!= 0){
                                    least = bestMove[L];
                                    pos = L;
                                }

                            } // end for

                            counter++;
                            nextMoveX = x + moveX[pos];
                            nextMoveY = y + moveY[pos];


                            arr[nextMoveX][nextMoveY] = counter;

                            top.x = nextMoveX;
                            top.y = nextMoveY;
                            for(int e = 0; e < 8; e++){
                                top.movesArray[e] = safe(nextMoveX + moveX[e],nextMoveY + moveY[e]);

                            }

                            locate.push(top);


                        } // end if (i=7)

                    } // end for i
                } // end else





    } // end while


} // end solve
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault) because you are trying to write past the size of arr.

How is arr declared? Do you make sure that when you do this:

```
arr[nextMoveX][nextMoveY] = counter;
```

nextMoveX and nextMoveY are within the array dimension values as declared(or malloc'd)?

Comment: int arr[8][8]; 

There is a bool safe(x,y) function that checks if the move is legal.

Comment: Try printing the values of nextMoveX, nextMoveY before this assignment. Both of them should be less than 8. Which OS are you on? Linux, Mac OSX, Windows?

Comment: windows and it there is a check to make sure it is less than 8. I just don't understand why it's never solving the problem. It doesn't appear to be coming to a valid solution and I have no idea what to change.